# session variable values cannot be display in the email message?

Tags: php, email, session, variables, sendmail

need help to solve display session variables values in message function problem is that `sessions variable values` cannot display on the message when the users got the email?

in the message mail function it is only showing the variable names not showing variables values?

```
session_start();
if(is_array($_SESSION['product1'])){
$max=count($_SESSION['product1']);  
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
$new_product=$_SESSION['product1'][$i];
$new_itemcode=$_SESSION['itemcode3'][$i];
$new_image=$_SESSION['image12'][$i];
$new_sizes=$_SESSION['sizes12'][$i];    
$new_price=$_SESSION['price12'][$i];    


$message .='<tr>
<td>'.implode ($new_itemcode).'</td>
<td>'.implode ($new_product).'</td>
<td><img src="http://demo.com/admin/'.implode ($new_image).'" 
width="150" height="150" /></td>
<td>'.implode ($new_sizes).'</td>
<td>'.implode ($new_price).';$total=$total+implode ($new_price).</td>
<td>'.$total.'</td>
</tr>';

}}

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: Demo.Com<$your_email>\r\n" .  
//"Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Email Demo Image**

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have `session_start();` at top of your page. Also you are missing `'` in third last </td>. If you can see the color difference above.

Comment: @Rikesh `session_start();` already on the top of your page?

Comment: Before sending email just log the $message variable to check if the values are coming.

Comment: correct the code first their is syntax error in code in `<img src="'.http://demo.com/implode ($new_product).'"?>` this should be `<img src="'.http://demo.com/implode ($new_product).'"/>`

Comment: and there is another mistake. `<img src="http://demo.com/'.implode ($new_product).'"/>` use this and then try you have close the string at wrong place.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha ok img path which is not correct but what about others variable values?

Comment: @edgematrix - Debug `echo $message;`.

Comment: few things you need to do to debug. first one echo the `$message` second things define the `$message` out site of the if condition and then check the `$message` after the if condition and you will get the solution.

Comment: @Rikesh i did `debug echo $message` it is only showing which is post image?